# File viewer web part renaming file in document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, file, fileviewer

I added a file viewer web part in SharePoint Online page and uploaded file from local desktop.
When I wanted to modify or add some changes in file, I do changes in local computer file and I am deleting the web part and adding new file viewer web part (as upload option unavailable in change file) and upload the new file.

The issue here is the file is renaming by adding numbers in suffix that doesn't make sense.
So, my question is

1. How the file in document library are being renamed?
2. How to upload a new file viewer web part instead of making it a new file?

Answer (score 0):

@Rajana Deepak,

The file viewer web part will rename the uploaded files to prevent overwriting existing files. These files will be stored in Shared Documents library.

If you want to update the showing file, you can first change back its name. Then upload the changed local file to Shared Documents library to overwrite the existing one. The file viewer will show the new content.

Also you can [connect the File viewer web part to a Document library](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-file-viewer-web-part-e53a9602-e7b3-4fff-9126-de2f18d1900c) web part and show files dynamically based on what a user selects in the Document library web part.

BR

Comment: How it is renaming the file? It is adding numbers as suffix like _13016, which the number doesn't make any sense.

Comment: We cannot know how it's renaming the file. That file viewer webpart is first-party, closed source. Microsoft hasn't exposed the source code. when it's uploading, the name is changed. Maybe it just a random num. it just prevents from overwriting the existing file in Shared document library